# How to prompt user to change password with a certain complexity in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords

I have to change the passwords of about 100 computers connected in a network all of which are running either Linux Mint or Ubuntu 14.04. How would I approach this with the help of a script and a server pushing it to the computers?

Comment: Depending on the kind of script you have in mind, this question would be better off in either [SU] or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: Thanks for replying! What script do you think would work best?